# Give the same padding percentage to unrelatable divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website's Architecture in which I would like to set the same padding percentage based to two div (A and B), but they share no parent and arent sibling, is there a way to do so ?

```
row
|-col-md-3
|   |-div A
|
|-col-md-9
    |-row
       |-col-md-1
           |-div B
```

I've tried to give `height: 100%` to each of their parent's divs so that it allows div A and div B to have the same height but in the end the padding% is always different, am I missing something ?

Comment: Show the actual HTML and CSS please, not ASCII art. [mcve]

Comment: That's it, Div A and Div B are angular related, so nothing much to see here.

Comment: Well then not much to say either.

Comment: There's a [very basic plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BwfYFssIKwaHHLHO8iF5?p=preview) explaining what my problem is

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties: _“The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'.”_ But since you know that col-md-3 is 25% wide, and col-md-9 75%, you should be able to calculate that into the actual padding percentage you need to get the same effective value for both.

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to specify the padding in a viewport unit in this case.

Comment: @CBroe so for instance if I apply a 5% padding-top on a col-md-3, I would have to apply a 15% one on a col-md-9 ?

Comment: Nah, rather the other way around. But probably not that much, and it probably won’t be integer values either. I really think viewport units instead of percentages might be the easier way to go here.

Comment: I'll dig into it, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging a bit into what were viewport units after the comments of @CBroe, I understood that it applies a value based on the viewport height and width, whatever the parent div's height, [I updated the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BwfYFssIKwaHHLHO8iF5?p=preview) in the comments to illustrate what this is all about.

```
.custom-padding {
  padding-top: 8vh; // This can be applied to every part of your website in which you want to set a padding, ignoring heights and widths compared to percentages and pixels
}
```